# Is there any Admob download tracking code for the iPhone that uses the IDFA instead of the UDID?

Tags: objective-c, admob, udid

Admob has provided some tracking code to track downloads of your iPhone app that are sent through ads.

https://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1704628&topic=1623717&ctx=topic

However it uses the UDID for tracking. Is there any way to use the IDFA (iOS 6 UDID replacement) instead of the UDID (as the compiler throws warnings saying that the UDID is deprecated)?

Comment: did you have a response for that ? can you share ?
Google doc : https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1704628?hl=fr
still not up to date.